# how to change word with javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<p class="author">
  hipstr 發表在 <a href="http://www.pixnet.net/">痞客邦 PIXNET</a> 
  <a href="http://hipstr.pixnet.net/blog/post/146448884#comments">留言</a>(0) 
  <span class="author-views">人氣(
    <span id="BlogArticleCount-146448884"></span>)
  </span>
  <a title="編輯" href="http://panel.pixnet.cc/blog/articleedit?blogarticle_id=146448884&blog=hipstr">
    <img title="編輯" alt="edit this article" src="//s.pixfs.net/blog/images/choc/bedit.gif" border="0">
  </a>
  <a title="刪除" href="javascript:pix.delArticle(146448884, false);">
    <img title="刪除" alt="delete this article" src="//s.pixfs.net/blog/images/choc/bdelete.gif" border="0">
  </a>
</p>
<!-- .author //-->
<br>
```

hello, everyone.
I am trying to replace"留言" with "comments"
I've tried http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp
but it didn't work. anyone can help out? thanks.

Comment: Show us the code that did not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use this:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('author'), function(comment) {
    comment.innerHTML = comment.innerHTML.replace('留言', 'comments');
});
```

Comment: thank you so much. it works.

Comment: however, how can i make "hipstr 發表在 痞客邦 PIXNET"dispeare?

Comment: @dex `comment.innerHTML.replace('留言', 'comments').replace('hipstr 發表在 痞客邦 PIXNET', '');`

Comment: thank you for your help. it works!：）